# Facebook Auth Dialog – Extended Permissions – How to make them mandatory

Tags: facebook, desktop-application

I am developing a desktop Facebook app, that simply won't work if the user doesn't grant some extended permissions.

To authorize my app, I point the user to :

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=PERMISSIONS_I_NEED&display=popup&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token
```

This works fine; however, a problem arises when the user doesn't grant some of the extended permissions.

There is an in my opinion extremely suboptimal solution over at https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/576/. The article basically tells says to repromt the user if he/she didn't grant the necessary permissions, which simply makes no sense. The only result of that is a confused user; for him/her, it will seem like the permissions are optional, when in fact they are not.

So, is there a better way? For instance, can I (the developer) specify that some of the extended permissions are mandatory?

Comment: Unfortunately we can't. That seems to be the "whole idea" behind extended permissions. 

For example: Facebook automatically sets "email" as a required ermission, when in fact most applications don't really require the user's email.

Comment: Are there special apps? Because now I've been checking the permissions of some apps and it seems some of them have the Publish_stream permission as mandatory ("Obligatorio"). http://dl.dropbox.com/u/49094601/1.PNG & http://dl.dropbox.com/u/49094601/2.PNG